# Read Values of a Scatter Plot Programatically- Highstock

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to read the values of a scatter plot in Highstock programatically? i want to read the value of the currently hovered point

For other series types, i am grabbing the currently hovered values as

```
//e is the click event
var f = chart.pointer.normalize(e);
var index = chart.pointer.getIndex(f);
var pt = serie.tooltipPoints[index];
//Now can access pt.x , pt.y
```

tooltipPoints is not available on scatter plot && if i use

```
serie.processedYData[index]
```

it gives me wrong values. i have kept the grouping enabled yet, the graph doesn't group the scatter serie. Is that the default behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [mouseOver](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.scatter.point.events.mouseOver) event?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This would only work when i hover over the actual point. But i am using a crosshair to read all current values. So when the cursor is at x=time1 anywhere on the chart, i would like to read its values